# Use php to load images and minimize HTTP requests

Tags: php, image, httprequest, pagespeed

**Goal**: minimizing the loading time of my website

I did lots of scans and speed tests.

They all indicate, there is lots of time spent uselessly, waiting for a HTTP response.
The time spent actually sending data is very small compared to that.

Screenshot of a 'speed test':

[image]

I started loading all the scripts and styles in PHP and just echoing them:

```php
<!-- loading a style -->
<style><?php echo file_get_contents("style.css"); ?></style>

<!-- loading a script (similar) -->
<script type="text/javascript"><?php echo file_get_contents("script.js"); ?></script>
```

That does work, however, the images still slow things down a little. How do I use php to read them and echo them as a `<img>` tag?

(The mentioned website is https://www.finnmglas.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone seeking answers to this:

You should not echo back images with PHP into the main file:

- It messes up the loading time (makes it way longer)
- And it delays the first render of your website. Even if you have less requests, you will want to have a quick first render (users will notice the delay)

Echoing images from a separate PHP file and including a `<img>` tag pointing at that PHP should not be a problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add data instead url to `src` attribute:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<? php echo base64_encode($data) ?>" />
```

but I recommend this for small images. Better way for more small images is use it as sprites: https://www.toptal.com/developers/css/sprite-generator/

and for css/javascript use some minify preprocessor: `gulp` `gulp-clean-css` `gulp-uglify-es`

Comment: So if I have a jpeg stored on my server, I can replace the mentioned `$data` by `file_get_contents("image.jpeg")` and it will work?

Comment: It did work! I do not actually use it because it is slower to render on mobile devices - but thank you, it did perfectly answer my question

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same kind of issue of wait and lag...

there are many factors, the location of the server, location of the visitor (in the picscreen case ; location of the server that did the test), routers between the internet provider, etc...

I discovered that using a CDN is way better, the browser will connect to the CDN that have many servers around the world, then cloudflare ask your server and cache the HTML, js, css, images, videos.... so that delivery to the end point becomes way more faster

you can try https://www.cloudflare.com/

Comment: Thank you - technically that is awesome but that would probably overcomplicate my legal note and privacy policy (I am in Germany haha)

Comment: @finnmglas Hi, another solution is cloudinary put images, audio and videos in cloudinary https://cloudinary.com/ and put your images in `<img src="...cloudinary_url..."`